# How to save a GNOME 3 session

Tags: gnome3

GNOME 2 allows one to either save the session automatically or manually (i.e. *save the session as it looks right now*). This is a nice feature because it restores the various desktop states between logins (and system restarts):

- which apps were open
- where (physically) on the desktop were they open
- what specific window sizes were these apps set to

Looking around, I can't find the feature in GNOME 3? Did I not look hard enough?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Normally you would `Alt-F2` to run gnome-session-properties, and select "Automatically remember running applications when logging out" under the Options tab.

However, it is broken at the moment. There is a bug filed:

https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=647359

Comment: That works on Fedora 15 (is it even the same bug?).

Comment: If Fedora uses a vanilla Gnome3, then yes. So you got it working in spite of the bug, or with it?

Comment: I didn't do anything special. I just selected the option, and can log out and in without a problem, and my session gets restored.

Comment: Odd. The bug is still open... Oh well, at least it is working for you.

Comment: for what it's worth, this is most definitely working for me right now in Fedora 16. Thanks jason!

Answer (score 19):

Try using dconf Editor, here are the steps

1. Open dconf Editor
2. Goto org/gnome/gnome-session
3. Check the property called "**auto_save_session**"

The description says "*If enabled, gnome-session will save the session automatically.*"

If you don't have dconf Editor installed, the setting can also be changed via the command line with:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.SessionManager auto-save-session true
```

Good luck!

Comment: This works on Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Works on debian 8.6

Comment: I don't have `dconf-editor`, there is some problem with the graphic interface. How do you do this same operation using `dconf` in terminal?

Comment: Use `gsettings`, just look it up.

Answer (score 2):

Sadly in 11.10
`gnome-session-properties`
doesn't offer any Option tab with Auto Save Session toggle.

So I installed `gconf-editor` to flip `/apps/gnome-session/options/auto_save_session` to TRUE.

Not sure if it works.  Once I had to add that missing key as boolean.

Comment: Update: even with this setting, not really, yet, if at all in Gnome3/Unity. Fuller discussion at http://askubuntu.com/a/78692/38636

Comment: Or just `gsettings set org.gnome.SessionManager auto-save-session true`

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a little library/command line tool which allow saving and restoring sessions and has support for different monitors setups as well as virtual desktops. It requires NodeJS to be installed.

### Installation

```
npm install -g linux-window-session-manager
```

### Usage

Save the current session to ~/.lwsm/sessionData/DEFAULT.json

```
lwsm save
```

Save the current session to ~/.lwsm/sessionData/my-session.json

```
lwsm save my-session
```

Restore the session from ~/.lwsm/sessionData/DEFAULT.json

```
lwsm restore
```

Restore the session from ~/.lwsm/sessionData/my-session.json

```
lwsm restore my-session
```

Gracefully close all running apps before starting the session

```
lwsm restore --closeAllOpenWindows
```

Check it out: https://github.com/johannesjo/linux-window-session-manager

Answer (score 1):

It works from the CLI - `gnome-session-properties` brings up the dialog. I'm not sure where it is on the menu. You can't run it from the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> command window with that command though.

Comment: Just to give an update, it runs fine from the Alt+F2 command window in gnome 3.4 from debian.

Comment: in Ubuntu 12.04 LTS it runs from cli or `Alt+F2` (`Mod4+r` in `awesomewm`). But running it from anywhere, the `auto_save_session` option doesn't appear.